# How long should it take to install Ubuntu onto a Nexus 7?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu into my nexus 7. I'm manually installing Ubuntu into my tablet because the other way gives me a checksum error. So I let it install and 10 hours later I came back and it was still installing. It says:

```
    sending 'userdata' (717793 KB)...
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

*Also check that Nexus 7 is not 'sleeping', by pressing on/off button briefly.*

---

If you are "installing manually", what steps are you using?

*This may be the cause of your problems.*

Did you download ALL files first? **`phablet-flash cdimage-touch -d grouper -b -D`**

---

What error (and at what stage) do you get when you attempt to use the **phablet-flash** tool to install?

(*I just installed to Nexus 7, with no issues.*)

Comment: I was using this web-page: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation
and it doesn't tell you to install phablet-tools. So I have changed web-page to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install. If there are any more issues I will reply back.

Comment: **Good.** The actual install files (and FTP site) referenced (in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, otherwise I will wait another 10+ hours without any result.

From the image size I know you downloaded the image from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu-active/daily-preinstalled/current/
The time stamp is 26-Feb-2013

I found a newer image (time stamp at 25-Apr-2013) here:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/raring/release/

And it works for me.

Send the image to the 'userdata' partition should take no more than 3mins